# Insert break or divide one line by another

Tags: equations

I use [an online LaTeX editor](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) to finish a series of equations: I want to break one line so that it's divided by the second.

This is what I currently have:

```
[c/[2*G*m/c^2]]/[m/[h/(2*pi)]*[h*[c/[2*pi*[c/[2*G*(200*$\odot$)/c^2]]]]^4/c^2]/c^4]=>1
```

However, I want something like this:

```
[c/[2*G*m/c^2]]
/
[m/[h/(2*pi)]*[h*[c/[2*pi*[c/[2*G*(200*M⊙︎)/c^2]]]]^4/c^2]/c^4]=>1
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You should try with `\frac{<num>}{<denom>} \geq 1`. Does that work for you?

Comment: I'm getting a 'blocked word' error, \begin{equation}
 \underline{[c/[2*G*m/c^2]]}
{[m/[h/(2*pi)]*[h*[c/[2*pi*[c/[2*G*(200*M⊙︎)/c^2]]]]^4/c^2]/c^4]}=>1

Comment: Check [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dZlU.png).